# Worth adding indexes on a column just to make them a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-optimization

I have an `invitations` table in my database, which has got a `from` and `to` columns, which are both foreign keys for the `userId` column in my `users` table.

For example, if User # 1 invited User # 2 to do something, then in the `invitations` table, `from` will be 1, and `to` will be 2.

I will use the `to` column in where statements, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM invitations WHERE `to` = $currentUserId
```

But the `from` column will never be used in WHERE statements.

From what I've read, you should only add an index on the columns which will be used in WHERE statements, however I've also read that you should always create Foreign keys.

Does it make sense for me to create an index on `from` just to add a foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of foreign keys, you should add one depending on what you do with users.

Internally, your fkeys will fire an action on any insert/update/delete of invitations, but also on any update/delete of users(id).

The first of these will use the index on users(id) to check if the user exists.

The other will essentially run a query that goes: `do whatever you defined to do on update/delete from invitations where to/from = :id`.

So, if you change the id of users (very unlikely) you can make use of an index. And if you occasionally delete users (only slightly more likely), you can make use of the index.

And as point out in the other answer, indexes are also useful for queries with an order by/limit clause.

Comment: If I set the update action for a foreign key to be `NO ACTION`, will that make it any faster to do inserts/updates to a table?

Comment: No.  The system will still have to verify that there is no constraint violation after a delete in the referenced table (users), and it will still have to do a SELECT * FROM referencingtable (invitations) where foreignkey = deletedFKvalue to achieve that.  You still need an index to avoid a full table scan occurring on the referencingtable (invitations) upon an update/delete in the referencedtable (users).

Answer (score 1):

> you should only add an index on the columns which will be used in WHERE statements

It is not so cut and dry. It is a good rule of thumb, but there is more to it than just this.

You should also index columns that you order by often and always, always test before and after a change to see if you have improved performance.

Foreign keys in general will not benefit from having an index defined on them, so long as they are not part of where/order by clauses. If they are, you should index them. (again, rules of thumb).

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/presentations/presentation-oscon2000-20000719/index.html) looks like a good resource for optimizing MySQL - look towards the bottom where it explains about indexing.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't answer my question, is it a good reason to add indexes just to make them foreign keys?

Comment: @Click Upvote - I don't quite understand how adding an index makes a column a foreign key.

Comment: A column must be an index for it to be a foreign key, isn't that so?

Comment: @Click Upvote - It looks like this is how MySQL works. However, it is more important that your database design is right than if an index is defined or not.